# When is log-transformation appropriate in unit-root testing?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, stationarity, logarithm, unit-root

In applied work in economics when people perform unit-root tests on level variables they virtually always transform them first by using natural logarithms.

However, I wonder if this is always warranted. I understand that one should take logs when the relationships are non-linear, or when the data have skewed distributions (unless logs are not appropriate because data are negative or we are dealing with rates etc).  This is also a practical advice one finds in econometric handbooks (e.g. Verbeek (2008), Guide to Modern Econometrics). However, is this warranted when none of the reasons above applies?

For example, I am trying to test predictions of a theoretical model which says that output of certain firms should be stationary and the model itself 'spits out' result which says that output $Y$ should follow

$Y_t = \delta Y_{t-1} +\epsilon$

where the model itself shows that there there is no reason to correct for possible non-linearity (the model also says that $\delta<1$ which is what I try to test). In addition, to my best knowledge in most unit-root tests like ADF skewness is less of an issue because the distribution is already assumed to be skewed under the null (but please correct me if I am wrong/misunderstand this). I am not sure if I am missing something but in this case it seems to me that it would be more appropriate to run the unit-root tests (for example ADF) just on levels of $Y_t $ rather than $\ln(Y_t)$.

In addition  in the  panel data I have on output of different firms where output is sometimes recorded with zero. Of course, this issue can be resolved simply by using $\ln(1+Y_t)$, but from an intuitive standpoint it seems superfluous to do all this without giving readers some concrete reason why data should be transformed in this way.

Hence my questions:

1. Are there some valid reasons to take $\ln(1+Y_t)$ given the information provided in the above?
2. If the answer to above would be negative, would taking $\ln(1+Y_t)$ raise some eyebrows as being incorrect/suspicious?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115951/discussion-on-question-by-1muflon1-when-is-log-transformation-appropriate-in-uni).

Comment: This is public so hopefully he won't get angry with me putting it here. IMHO, if one was rating time-series econometricians and using both theoretical and applied ability in the ranking, he might be top 10 in the world. But that's just my humble opinion and I'm a little biased towards kind researchers who actually play with data.  https://econweb.ucsd.edu/~jhamilton/

Comment: @mlofton oh you meant that Hamilton! The author of the time series bible Time Series Analysis - I thought that is just some user with similar name. Well good to know the person responds also to emails from individuals. I will consider sending him an email. thanks for all these pointers

Comment: no problem and good luck with your project. maybe that link that explains why people take logs is useful. I'm gonna read it later tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: @1muflon1: A weird twilight zone type of event just occured: the "why do people take logs" link was written by Professor Hamilton. Yet, when I googled for why people take logs, I put zero in about James Hamilton. That is really weird !!!! The link explains it pretty well. Essentially, whenever you have  numbers where percent increases (decreases ) are more interesting than absolute increases ( or decreases ) one should take logs because it kind of then brings everything into "percent changes" space. It's like a new basis in matrix algebra so that + or - now means + or - the percentage.

Comment: One more comment: The only thing weird about what I say above is that, if I understand it correctly, it almost seems like, if you take logs of one variable then you need to take logs of all of them. Otherwise, you're comparing apples and oranges ? Maybe that's generally the case. I'm not sure.